# How to print api in django console instead if queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from access.models import SeekerRegister
from .models import CandidateDetails,Social,CvDetails,KeySkills,CandidateCompanyDetails,CandidateEducationDetails,ContactInfo


class MainSeekerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SeekerRegister
        fields = ('contact_info',
                'candidate_details','social',
                'cv_details','key_skills',
                'candidate_company_details',
                'candidate_education_details',
                'seeker_language',
                'seeker_name','seeker_email',
                'seeker_contact_no','verified')
        depth = 1
```

views.py

```
class AdvanceSearchViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset =  SeekerRegister.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MainSeekerSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = SeekerRegister.objects.all()

        if self.request.query_params.get('skills_any', None) is not None:
            skills_any = self.request.query_params.get('skills_any', None).split(",")
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"code":401,"msg":"skills_any is required"})

        if self.request.query_params.get('skills_must', None) is not None:
            skills_must = self.request.query_params.get('skills_must', None).split(",")
        else:
            skills_must = None

        if (skills_any is not None
         and skills_must is None:
            filters =  Q(key_skills__skills__in=skills_any) & Q(key_skills__skills__in=skills_must)
        else:
            filters =  Q(key_skills__skills__in=skills_any)

        queryset = queryset.filter(filters)
        print(queryset)
        return queryset
```

result in browser:

```
    [
     {
        "key_skills": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "skills": "python",
            "versions": "3.600",
            "experience": "2.000",
            "user": 3
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "skills": "angular",
            "versions": "3.600",
            "experience": null,
            "user": 3
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "skills": "java",
            "versions": "16.060",
            "experience": null,
            "user": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

In console when i am printing **queryset** it is coming 
How can i get api in console whatever i am getting in browser.

Because i have edit something in the **skills** of **dictionary**.

Please have a look.

I have sharded serializers and view file .

is there any way to modify the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solution to check result or console in api end to overwrite list endpoint of yours viewset and print/console there.

Add this function in your AdvanceSearchViewSet.

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        // print here 
        print('response', serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: with removing get_queryset function or without??

Comment: without removing that. If you doing some custom validation there.

Comment: add this in your top of code, from rest_framework.response import Response

Comment: the results are coming tuples

Comment: is there any way to convert

Comment: you can use , vars . i mean print(vars(serializer.data))

Comment: actually i am not able to convert from OrderedDict to json

Comment: I am not get your point. serializer.data will passed that response in Json format in front-end.

Comment: get it. fixed the issue.Thanks